# Load More Button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently approached to javascript and jQuery; I would like to create a load more button for the image grid on my website, the grid have 4 column and right now 16 images with a hover overlay effect and with a  tag . I tried to follow many tutorials, I can't find and understand the mistake I made.

The code has been corrected in the following anwers

```js
$(function() {
  $(".Box-Hidden").slice(0, 8).show();

  $("#loadMoreCont").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $(".Box-Hidden:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
    if ($(".Box-Hidden:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1500);



  });
});
```

```css
.GridContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.Portfolio {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.Box-Hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GridContent">
  <div class="Portfolio">
    <!-----image 1 ------>
    <div class="Box-Hidden">
      <a href="#" class="SpanProp1">
        <div class="GridItemsCont">

          <img src="#" class="gridimg">
          <div class="infos infocolor1">
            <p>logo</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-----image 2 ------>
    <div class="Box-Hidden">
      <a href="#" class="SpanProp2 ">
        <div class="GridItemsCont">
          <img src="#">
          <div class="infos infocolor2">
            <p>logo</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-----total 16 images----->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="loadMoreCont">
  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  <a href="#"><img class="loadImg" src="images/arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code are that the classes and ID's are mixed up in the JS. In particular the `loadMore` button and how many items you're choosing to show via "slice". It would also help to use a more general or "semantic" friendly name for your containers instead of `Box-Hidden` because it's not always hidden and it's purpose is more like a card block, so naming it something like "card" might be best. The example below shows the Load More button and then disappears after displaying the rest of the cards.

```js
// slice is choosing the first 2 instances of "Box-hidden" and showing them
$(".Box-Hidden").slice(0, 2).show();
// if there are Box-Hidden set to display:none (hidden) then show the loadMore button 
if ($(".Box-Hidden:hidden").length != 0) {
  $("#loadMore").show();
}

$("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(".Box-Hidden:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
  // if there are no more hidden Box-Hidden's then hide the loadMore button
  if ($(".Box-Hidden:hidden").length == 0) {
    $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
  }
  // This is not related to the show more, this just brings you back up the page
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
  }, 1500);


});
```

```css
.GridContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.Portfolio {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.Box-Hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GridContent">
  <div class="Portfolio">
    <!-----image A ------>
    <div class="Box-Hidden" style="display: none;">
      <a href="#" class="SpanProp2 ">
        <div class="GridItemsCont">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=1">
          <div class="infos infocolor2">
            <p>logo</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-----image B ------>
    <div class="Box-Hidden" style="display: none;">
      <a href="#" class="SpanProp2 ">
        <div class="GridItemsCont">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=2">
          <div class="infos infocolor2">
            <p>logo</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-----image 1 ------>
    <div class="Box-Hidden" style="display: none;">
      <a href="#" class="SpanProp1">
        <div class="GridItemsCont">

          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=3" class="gridimg">
          <div class="infos infocolor1">
            <p>logo</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-----image 2 ------>
    <div class="Box-Hidden" style="display: none;">
      <a href="#" class="SpanProp2 ">
        <div class="GridItemsCont">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=4">
          <div class="infos infocolor2">
            <p>logo</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-----total 16 images----->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="loadMoreCont">
  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  <a href="#"><img class="loadImg" src="images/arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you find this was helpful and the correct answer, please mark it as such by clicking on the arrow next to this answer.

Comment: thank you so much ! it seems that the problem was that I hadn't put  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.... on my Html beyond the fact that i've installed and  added <script  src="jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
$("#loadMoreCont").on(...)
```

it is supposed you have a html tag having the **id** with that name:

```
<div id="loadMoreCont">
...
</div>
```

When you use

```
$(".loadMoreCont").on(...)
```

it is supposed you have a html tag having the **class** with that name:

```
<div class="loadMoreCont">
...
</div>
```

**Update**

```
$(function () {
    $(".Box-Hidden").slice (0, 2).show(); // showing 2 initial images

    $(".loadMoreCont").on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(".Box-Hidden:hidden").slice(0,2).slideDown(); // adding 2 images on load more click
        if ($(".Box-Hidden:hidden"). length == 0){
            $("#load").fadeOut ('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
});
});
```

Your code seems work fine. I commented out some interesting lines.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! I fixed the error but it still doesn't work

Comment: I commented in the following answers the updated code, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

your #loadMoreCont JS file on line 4 is targeted at an ID (#).
but on your html loadMoreCont as a class (.)

Comment: thank you ! I fixed the error but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The question is: " I would like to create a load more button for the image grid on my website, the grid have 4 column and right now 16 images with a hover overlay effect and with a tag . I tried to follow many tutorials, I can't find and understand the mistake I made"

Here the updated code after the kind correction of the users @Kurohige and @WkL

HTML

```
    <div class="GridContent">
      <div class="Portfolio">
        <!-----image 1 ------>
        <div class="Box-Hidden">
          <a href="#" class="SpanProp1">
            <div class="GridItemsCont">

              <img src="#" class="gridimg">
              <div class="infos infocolor1">
                <p>logo</p>
                <button>Learn More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-----image 2 ------>
        <div class="Box-Hidden">
          <a href="#" class="SpanProp2 ">
            <div class="GridItemsCont">
              <img src="#">
              <div class="infos infocolor2">
                <p>logo</p>
                <button>Learn More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-----total 16 images----->
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="loadMoreCont">
  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  <a href="#"><img class="loadImg" src="images/arrow.png"></a>
</div>`
```

CSS

```
.GridContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.Portfolio {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.Box-Hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $(".Box-Hidden").slice (0, 8).show();

    $(".loadMoreCont").on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(".Box-Hidden:hidden"). slice(0,2).slideDown();
        if ($(".Box-Hidden:hidden"). length == 0){
            $("#load").fadeOut ('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);



});
});
</script>
<script  src="jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be an update to your code within the question and then you could mention in a comment below the question that you've updated it.